# Trying to simplify the checking of an IO Bool in an Attoparsec parser

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm trying to simplify the below code that's part of an attoparsec parser for a network packet, and I'm at a loss for a nice way to do it.

It starts with a call to `atEnd :: IO Bool` to determine if there's more to parse. I can't find a nicer way to use `atEnd` than to unwrap it from IO and then use it in an if statement, but it seems like there must be be a simpler way to check bool inside a monad. Here's the code:

```
maybePayload :: Parser (Maybe A.Value)
maybePayload = do
    e <- atEnd
    if e then return Nothing
    else do
        payload' <- char ':' *> takeByteString
        maybe mzero (return . Just) (maybeResult $ parse A.json payload')
```

The intention is to return `Nothing` if there is no payload, to return `Just A.Value` if there is a valid JSON payload, and for the parser to fail if there is a non-valid payload.

Here's the Packet record that eventually gets created:

```
data Packet = Packet
    { pID       :: Integer
    , pEndpoint :: String
    , pPayload  :: Maybe A.Value
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a lot of work you don't need to do. First you check if you're at the end of the data and return `Nothing` if that doesn't work out. That's just not necessary, because if you're at the end, any parser that requires content will fail, and using `maybeResult` will turn that failure into `Nothing`.

The only time your parser fails is with the case where the input has data which doesn't start with the character `:`, the rest of the time it succeeds, even if that's by returning `Nothing`.

The only actual parsing going on is checking for `:` then using `A.json`. I think you're trying to write the whole program inside one parser, whereas you should just do the parsing on its own then call that as necessary. There's no need to check for end of data, or to make sure you get the whole content - that's all built in for free in a parser. Once you get rid of all that unnecessary checking, you get

```
payload :: Parser A.Value
payload = char ':' *> A.json
```

If you want to you can use that as `maybeResult $ parse payload input` to get a `Maybe A.Value` that's not additionally wrapped in a `Parser`. If you don't apply `maybeResult`, you can pattern match on the [Result](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.10.2.0/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#t%3aResult) returned to deal separately with `Fail`ure, `Partial` success and `Success`.

---

Edit: OK, clearer now, thanks:

- (If there's a colon followed by invalid json, fail)
- If there's a colon followed by valid json, succeed, wrapping it in Just
- If there's just end of input, succeed, returning Nothing

So we get:

```
maybePayload :: Parser (Maybe A.Value)
maybePayload = char ':' *> (Just <$> A.json)
            <|> (Nothing <$ endOfInput)
```

I've used `<$>` and `<$` from `Control.Applicative`, or if you prefer, from `Data.Functor`.

`<$>` is an infix version of `fmap`, so `Just <$> A.json` does `A.json` and wraps any output in `Just`.

`<$` is `fmap.const` so replaces the `()` from `endOfInput` with `Nothing`.

Comment: I edited the question to include the record I'm parsing into, which will hopefully make the intention more clear. If there's no payload but the rest of the packet parses, that's fine, but if there's something there that's not a valid payload, the packet parse will fail.

Comment: @jhickner I think I get you - is the edit what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to encode failure in Maybe when the parser monad already has a built-in notion of failure? The problem with using Maybe in this way is that the parser cannot backtrack.

You could try something like this (I haven't tried to typecheck it) and then use `option` in the caller:

```
payload :: Parser Value
payload = do
  payload' <- char ':' *> takeByteString
  let res = parse A.json payload'
  case res of
    Error msg -> fail msg
    Success a -> return a
```

Comment: I'm intentionally discriminating between the case when there's no payload, in which case I want ```Nothing``` returned (it ends up as the value of a payload field in a record), and the case where there is some payload present but it's not valid JSON, in which case I want the parsing of the entire packet to fail.